# Missing at Random vs Missing Completely at Random

Tags: mcar

From what I understood:

**MCAR** - missingness do not depend on the values of Y (observed or missed)

**MAR** - missingness depends only on the components of Y that are observed, and not on the components that are missing.

**Question:** Is MAR more restrictive than MCAR?? since it has a conditional factor? or that comparison can't be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it MCAR and MAR do **not** intersect, i.e. a sample can be assumed to be missing due to either one of these mechanisms but not both. In this sense you can say that:

- a value is MAR, if the "missingness" depends on **solely on observed** variables
- a value is MCAR, if the "missingness" depends **solely on unobserved** variables

Try to think of it more intuitively, a value can't be missing **completely** at random if we can (at least partially) account for its missingness with data at our disposal.

While I don't think you can make any theoretical claim about the restrictiveness of either category, in practice it **more likely** that the MAR mechanism stands and not the MCAR. In fact a lot of well known imputation strategies inherently assume that all all values are MAR (e.g. [MICE](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03)).

---

Finally, a clarification: if by $Y$ you mean just the labels, then your MAR statement is not 100% accurate. MAR essentially means that the information about the "missingness" (partially) lies in the data's features, i.e. $X$